# Add debug mode to bash script

Tags: bash, debugging, date, redirect

first of all, sorry for my bad english.

I want to enbale debug mode, with date. I was thinkging in a variable that use one type of redirection, or another, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBUG_MODE=1

if [ $CHAMAC_DEBUG = 0 ]; then
output=/dev/null
elif [ $CHAMAC_DEBUG = 1 ]; then
output=>( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done >> ~/output.log )
fi

echo "hi, im a echo" &> $output
```

But it dont work for me.... how can do it¿?¿?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "debug mode", but if you want to print additional output only when a particular variable is defined you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function print_debug {
  [ $DEBUG_MODE -eq 1 ] && echo "$(date) $1"
}

DEBUG_MODE=0
print_debug "Test 1"
DEBUG_MODE=1
print_debug "Test 2"
```

Output:

```non
$ ./test.sh
Test 2
```

You could also separate debug output from regular output by echoing debug messages to a different file descriptor:

```
function print_debug {
  [ $DEBUG_MODE -eq 1 ] && echo "$1" 1>&3
}
```

That way you can redirect STDOUT, STDERR and debug output to different files if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
debug () {
    date +"[%C] $*" >&2
}

if ... whatever ...; then
    dbg=debug
else
    dbg=:
fi

$dbg "script started"
:
```

Wherever you want to output a diagnostic, use `$dbg` instead of `echo`.

(You have to double any literal percent sign in your debug prints, or make the function slightly more complex.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate file descriptor for this (along with a few other fixes):

```
if [[ "${CHAMAC_DEBUG}" == "1" ]]
then
  exec 3>> ~/output.log
else
  exec 3>> /dev/null
fi

{ echo "$(date) : hi, im a echo"; } >&3
```

The process substitution syntax wants to see the name of a program, not a `bash` internal command like `while`. You could maybe get it to work using something like `>(bash -c 'some stuff here')`, but the above is simpler, I think. The only downside is you have to do your own date-stamping... If that's a problem, you could look into submitting your debug messages to `syslog` (via `logger`) and configure that to dump those specific messages in a file of their own...